# OnCollisionEnter2D() not Detecting Collisions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, game-physics, game-development

I am making a primarily 3D game, but with some 2D minigames. However, in one of these minigames, the player's OnCollisionEnter2D() is not detecting the collisions of any other object. My code is as follows:

```
public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    Debug.Log("CollisionOccurred");
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "PuzzleWall")
    {
        Debug.Log("Wall hit");
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, despite being put through multiple objects on several occasions, neither Debug.Log() has triggered.

I have tried the following to fix the problem (to no avail):

- Giving both the player and the other objects Rigidbody2D with Dynamic Body Type
- Giving both the player and the other objects BoxCollider2D with IsTrigger and correct Collider layout
- Placing the OnCollisionEnter2D() before the Update() in the same script
- Checking the tags on the other objects to make sure they align correctly
- Checked the Layer Collision Matrix to ensure that the objects on the layers can collide
- Reorganizing the objects in the Hierarchy
  The only hint I was able to find was that the objects/player keep moving on the z axis by 10^-6 despite the Rigidbody2D constraints.

Comment: if your collisions arent working - then you havent achieved .. "Giving both the player and the other objects BoxCollider2D with IsTrigger and correct Collider layout" if you have istrigger its not a collision its a trigger... (the location of code is irrelevant in a class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Collider2D components have IsTrigger enabled, then you need to use the function `OnTriggerEnter2D()` rather than `OnCollisionEnter2D()`. This is because when you have IsTrigger enabled, the collider does not behave like an actual collider, but rather a trigger.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up just removing the IsTrigger of the objects, maintaining the OnCollisionEnter2D() functions.